# Convert a part of ByteBuffer back to String

Tags: java, string, bytebuffer

I have a big `String` that was once converted to a `ByteBuffer` & then while reading later several times, only a portion of the `String`(overview of the text) needs to be presented, so I want to convert only a part of the `ByteBuffer` to `String`.

Is it possible to convert only a part of bytebuffer to string rather than [converting entire `Bytebuffer` to `String` & then using `substring()`]

Comment: You can't really do this, because some characters take up more than one byte. (Assuming your bytes are UTF-8 encoded, the platform default for Linux). Is it really a performance problem to convert the whole lot into a `String`?

Comment: I didn't profiled my code but I just wanted to avoid decoding entire BB _if possible_

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(yourstr));
    bbuf.position(0);
    bbuf.limit(200);
    CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
    String s = cbuf.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
}
```

Which should return chars from the byte buffer starting at 0. byte and ending in 200.

Or rather:

```
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(yourstr.getBytes());
    bbuf.position(0);
    bbuf.limit(200);

    byte[] bytearr = new byte[bbuf.remaining()];
    bbuf.get(bytearr);
    String s = new String(bytearr);
```

Which does the same but without explicit character decoding/encoding.

Decoding of course does happen in constructor of `String s` and it is platform dependent, so watch out.

Comment: i want to retrieve the _first 200 characters_ of the string. How would I do that ?

Comment: The number of bytes to decode depends on the charset, so I don't think there's a generic solution. For UTF-8, you could decode the first 800 bytes, then take a substring of the first 200 characters of the result. This should work because the length of an UTF-8 character is max 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// convert all byteBuffer to string
String fullByteBuffer = new String(byteBuffer.array());

// convert part of byteBuffer to string
byte[] partOfByteBuffer = new byte[PART_LENGTH];
System.arraycopy(fullByteBuffer.array(), 0, partOfByteBuffer, 0, partOfByteBuffer.length);
String partOfByteBufferString = new String(partOfByteBuffer.array());
```